# Why is it skipping lines in the txt in my code?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, txt

I am trying to make a password manager. I want it to ask the user what website they saved it for, and then give it the password and the username for it. Instead, it just skips through the text and doesn't show the username, but the password of the first 2 lines, not the username and password of the account.

This is my code:

```
def view_passwords():
    try:
        website = simpledialog.askstring("Enter Website", "Enter the website for the account:")
        with open(passwordsfile, 'r') as f:
            passwords = f.read()
            # Search for the account based on the provided website
            if website in passwords:
                # Split the passwords string based on the separator "|"
                entries = passwords.split("|")
                for entry in entries:
                    if "Website or app" in entry:
                        # Extract the username and password
                        username = entries[entries.index(entry) - 1].strip()
                        password = entries[entries.index(entry) + 1].strip()
                        messagebox.showinfo("Account Info", f"Website: {website}\n{username}\n{password}")
                        break
                else:
                    messagebox.showinfo("No Account", f"No account found for {website}.")
            else:
                messagebox.showinfo("No Account", f"No account found for {website}.")
    except FileNotFoundError:
        messagebox.showinfo("No Passwords", "No passwords found.")
```

This is my text file:

```
Username: hdhdh| Password: hshsh| Website or app: snsn
Username: dhhd| Password: shahhs| Website or app: [Z!+M7gt[_uw
Username: aaa| Password: $LCN}|d1HsrR| Website or app: ok
```

When I run it, this happens:

[image]

Can you guys help me?

Comment: You are reading your entire file into a single `str` with `f.read()`. You'll need to split that line on `\n`, *then* iterate over the lines to split them on `|` one-by-one.

Comment: If the file contents are **exactly** as shown, read line by line then split on whitespace. The relevant website or app value will be the last item in the list of tokens return from str.split(). Once you've identified the website or app, the username and password will be tokens 1 and 3 respectively (ignoring the trailing pipe)

Comment: You should be able to replace `passwords = f.read()` with `passwords = f.readlines()` to return an iterable of items splt at newlines (`\n`)

Comment: It would be better to store this using JSON or CSV. The format you're using is harder to parse. Your code never removes the prefixes like `Username:` and `Website or app:`, which shouldn't be in the file.